# input type=range Infinity max Value

Tags: angular, typescript

we want on an Input type range, where we show a label on the max side for example 2500€ +, that if a user clicks on it, the value of the max is Infinity.

```
HTML:
 <input
  class="slider__input"
  type="range"
  [disabled]="disabled"
  [(ngModel)]="value"
  [max]="max"
  [min]="min"
  [step]="step"
/>

COMPONENT:
if (this.value === this.max) {
  this.value = Infinity;
  this.ngControl.control.patchValue(Infinity);
}
```

i did this and it works but the UI the Bubble of the slider is in the Middle and the Value of the input if i check it in the console is 1300 but if i save my form i get Infinity.

[image]

how do i get the Bubble at the and ?

```js
const input = document.getElementById("range");

function setInfinity() {
    console.log('INfINITY', range.value)
  range.value = Infinity;
}
```

```html
    <input
      id="range"
      class="slider__input"
      type="range"
      value="0"
      max="2500"
      min="0"
    />
    
    <button type="button" onclick="setInfinity()">
    Set infinity
    </button>
```

Comment: Don't change the input's value. Just treat the max value as `Infinity` in your code.

Comment: `const value = input.value === maxValue ? Infinity : input.value`

Comment: but even then its slide to the middle if select the max

i though of this too but only the slider knows the max value ... the form is two parents above where i do the save ... i would have to give the max value trhough two childs

Comment: i got an idea from your idea @Dima

Comment: Okay, then just substitute `maxValue` with `input.max`

Comment: `const value = input.value === input.max ? Infinity : input.value`